# Fluent hibernate - generatedby queryresult?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Normally we have in Hibernate with c# (fluent hibernate) `ID.(x=>x.Column).Generatedby.Sequence("blabla")`;

Its possible to make something like "generated by query " ? I mean that I can specify the query or stored procedure to get the result in a sequence?

I need to do this because :

my `ID` is `varchar` . When I generate by `"generatedby.sequence("sequence"); "` I receive the error about the integral types, that of course is correct.

So I wrote a function to solve this. Where I make the process of an ID value as `varchar (xxx0001,xxxx0002.......)` auto-incrementing. That's work just fine.

Now I need to assign that result(of the function) to my ID in the mapped class.

There is a way to do it? to put the result of
 `"SELECT GenerateSequencesAccountsr('SEQ_TEST',1) AS NextValue FROM dual"` to my " Id(x=>x.account)????.

I was thinking already in a possible solution to call the query before to insert but I'm trying to keep my "base" total generic. like:

```
        public virtual void SaveData(object cls)
        {
            using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    session.SaveOrUpdate(cls);
                    tx.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCustomSqlGenerator : IPersistentIdentifierGenerator
{
    private SqlString _sql = new SqlString("your select here");

    public string GeneratorKey()
    {
        return _sql.ToString();
    }

    public string[] SqlCreateStrings(Dialect dialect)
    {
        // TODO: return sql Create of sqlfunction
    }

    public string[] SqlDropString(Dialect dialect)
    {
        // TODO: return sql DROP of sqlfunction
    }

    public object Generate(ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = session.Batcher.PrepareCommand(CommandType.Text, _sql, SqlTypeFactory.NoTypes);
            IDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = session.Batcher.ExecuteReader(cmd);
                try
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    object result = IdentifierGeneratorFactory.Get(reader, NHibernateUtil.String, session);
                    return result;
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Batcher.CloseCommand(cmd, reader);
            }
        }
        catch (DbException sqle)
        {
            throw ADOExceptionHelper.Convert(session.Factory.SQLExceptionConverter, sqle, "could not get next sequence value");
        }
    }
}
```